# Adb Error on "adb devices"

Tags: android, adb

When I type in "adb devices", the output is "error: protocol fault (no status)". The adb functionality is broken in both Android Studio and Eclipse, so it's a problem with the connection, I believe. I tried to kill adb.exe from the Task Manager, but it's not listed in the processes. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was my parental controls software. The adb.exe works fine with it disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Try to **open** the this directory :

```
adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\sdk\platform-tools
```

Hold shift + right mouse click. Select open command prompt here.

After that,

```
in the command window type
```

**adb kill-server**

and then

**adb start-server**

then,

**adb devices**

See if the adb is started and if your device is visible on **eclipse** or **android 
studio**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the problem still persists. The kill-server command returns: * server not running *

Comment: Try doing just adb start-server and see if it shows, deamon started

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't show anything, it just goes to the next input.

Comment: The output should come like this :

* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *

Comment: Yeah, I think that's why it's not showing up in the process list. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: No. That's what makes me confused.

Comment: That's interesting.. The only way I do is that i kill server and then start server till the adb is enabled. Or try to restart your laptop/pc and see of the adb comes back.

Comment: I've restarted it already, the only thing I can think of it to allow adb.exe through the firewall. Would that do anything?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51365/discussion-between-mike20132013-and-electronicgeek)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem i faced in past, the solution worked for me is: 
Navigate to the plateform-tools(it is under SDK) and execute following commands on cmd.

- C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>set ADB_TRACE=1
- C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb start-server

I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Change your USB cable then it will resolve the issue.